# How do I see which questions I've edited (by suggesting edits)?

Tags: support, questions, edits, editor

I've edited several questions and had several edits accepted over the past week or so, but I can't seem to find my pending or accepted edits. Where can I see a list of questions I've edited?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Comment: If someone's confused about Nick's link, it refers to your own activity tab, so user neets will see what they are looking for. But if someone else wants to check neets activity tab, then use https://stackoverflow.com/users/22646080/neets?tab=activity&sort=suggestions (the link uses their user id).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above comments provide a direct link to this list. But the detailed procedure is:

- Click on your image in the navbar
- Click on "All Actions"
- Select the "Suggestions" tab